# Where does the other Ryder go after the end of Mass Effect Andromeda ('s main quest)?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

Playing as Sara Ryder, I can talk to my brother Scott in the Meridian area - formerly the Hyperion Habitation Deck - during the post-endgame "party" scene. But after that, I can't find Scott anymore, either on Meridian, or in the Nexus (at least the parts I've searched).

Where is Scott hiding? (Conversely, where is Sara hiding, for those who play as male/Scott Ryder?)

Comment: Can't confirm because I haven't checked, but Sara/Scott can usually be found in the Cryo Deck of the Hyperion. Have you looked there?

Comment: I can't figure out how to go there after the end of the game. Once the Hyperion is crashed on Meridian there seems to be no way to access anything but the Habitation Deck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading a lot of questions on this matter on various forums, I can conclude that Scott/Sara Ryder disappears from the game entirely after leaving the Hyperion post-final mission. The same thing happens with the Angaran AI, should you choose to keep her with SAM in the Hyperion.

It is currently unknown if this is a bug or by design.

Comment: Maybe they eloped....